# Serialize datetime lost information about timeZone with zulu format

Tags: c#, json.net, datetime-format, utc

When I try to use a JObject (Newtonsoft) I lost some data with zulu date format

```
var s = "{  \"DateTimeZulu\": \"2019-06-12T08:50:20.626Z\",  \"DateTimeUtc\": \"2019-06-12T08:50:20.626+00:00\" }";
var jsonEntity = (JObject.Parse(s));
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> current in jsonEntity)
{
    Console.WriteLine(current.Key + " - " + current.Value.ToString());
}
```

Actual  output:

```
DateTimeZulu - 12/06/2019 08:50:20  
DateTimeUtc - 12/06/2019 10:50:20
```

Expected  output:

```
DateTimeZulu - 12/06/2019 10:50:20  
DateTimeUtc - 12/06/2019 10:50:20
```

Comment: You can force Json.Net to use [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netframework-4.8) instead of DateTime which preserves time zones as DateTime has no notion of time zones. You can do this by using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(s, new JsonSerializerSettings { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset })`. This will correctly yield `12/06/2019 08:50:20` for both (not `12/06/2019 10:50:20`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information is not lost. If you'll check `current.Value` contents you'll see the difference in `Kind` property.

For the first value kind is `UTC`, for the second value kind is `Local`. If affects how the date will be converted to string.

You can convert DateTime between UTC and Local using `ToUniversalTime` or `ToLocalTime` functoins. Try following sample to see the difference:

```
    var s = "{  \"DateTimeZulu\": \"2019-06-12T08:50:20.626Z\",  \"DateTimeUtc\": \"2019-06-12T08:50:20.626+00:00\" }";
    var jsonEntity = (JObject.Parse(s));
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> current in jsonEntity)
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(current.Key + " - " + ((DateTime)current.Value).ToLocalTime().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(current.Key + " - " + ((DateTime)current.Value).ToUniversalTime().ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Tanks i will have à look tomorow with kind property if i can solve my problème with !